# Grepping for '../' (dot dot slash)

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to search my directory for files that contain `../` with `grep -r -n '../' *`, but I get lots of false positives. [`grep`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) is interpreting the period as a wild character, how do I stop this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just escape the dots:

```
grep -r -n '\.\./' *
```

Tested in [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin). Dot is of course a wildcard in [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Answer (score 1):

Escape the dots with backslashes: `\.`